# Why am I getting 'Exception Value: expected string or buffer' when submitting form?

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting an 'Exception Value: expected string or buffer' every time I submit my form.  It definitely seems like the issue is with the model field 'pub_date'.  I have attached my code and the traceback I'm getting.

My question is, what exactly is going wrong here and is there any way to work around it?

```
#MODELS

class Entry(models.Model):
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,blank=True)


#FORMS

class SellForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['pub_date']


#VIEWS

def get_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = SellForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            obj=f.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
    else:
        f = SellForm()
    return render(request, 'sell.html', {'form': f})


Traceback:
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/deal/accounts/views.py" in get_entry
  27.       form.save()
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  897.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  855.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  350.                                       prepared=False)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  911.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  895.         value = self.to_python(value)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  854.             parsed = parse_datetime(value)
File "/Users/benjamino/Desktop/deal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py" in parse_datetime
  67.     match = datetime_re.match(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /sell/
Exception Value: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: I am not sure how you are giving input or what are given as input, but it should be string or buffer, as error says.

Answer (score 0):

I is because here:

```
    obj=f.save(commit=False)
    obj.save()
```

you are saving a WHOLE form. For what?
I think it will be better to extract data from form fields and use them.
There is a built in form cleaned_data attribute. `f.cleaned_data` - and you will get dictionary 
of form field values.